# To keep xAxis constant when using tickPositions in the highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I fixed xAxis using tickPositions as follows, but I'm in trouble because the gap changes fluidly from data to data.

as follows
tickPositions: [0, 0.5, 1, 3, 5,20,50,100,200,400,800]

Can I change the line chart made using the as follows?

I want to make the graph implemented with hicharts in photo 1 constant as in photo 2.

Help me. I can't find it

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuHXO.jpg)

[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmAv6.jpg)

my xAxis option

```
      xAxis: {
          title: {
              text: '(m)',
              style: {
                  color: '#0a0a0a',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize:'15px'
              }
          },
          tickPositions: [0, 0.5, 1, 3, 5,20,50,100,200,400,800],
          lineColor: '#000000',
          gridLineColor: '#807f7f',
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color : '#0a0a0a',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize:'13px'
              },
          },
      },
```

ex) Data x,y

var legendData = [[0, 5], [0.5, 6], [1, 7], [3, 13], [5, 22],[100, 5],[200, 6], [400, 7] [800, 22]];

Category Issues Photo
[photo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAK5K.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use x-axis with categories and `tickmarkPlacement` set to `on`. For example:

```
xAxis: {
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
  tickWidth: 1,
  min: 0.5,
  max: data.length + 0.5,
  categories: [0, 0.5, 1, 3, 5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800],
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/28L1d6wc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

Comment: Thank you, bro

I succeeded in changing the shape of the graph with your answer, but one more problem occurred

The 5.8m part of the attached picture is the x-axis, but I didn't use the category originally, so it was displayed on the 5.8m part of the graph, but after using the category, it is displayed after 20, which is the 5.8 part of the category

I'm also continuing to look for a way and I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know if there's a good way. Your first reply alone was very helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @최인영, That's complicate things a bit. Each category has 1 x-value, so to position a point between categories, you need to use floats. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ng6se9or/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I'll use this to apply it.

Thank you again! You are my benefactor